# How can I get the pixel data from an area of the screen (much) faster in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I understand that for some things it would be better to write certain things in C++, but I'd really like to be able to do this in AHK:

I want to be able to retrieve the pixel data from a 100x300 area of the screen, however `PixelGetColor` is way too slow. Here's a test demonstrating that it takes about 0.02 seconds per pixel, which is roughly 11.5 hours to get the pixel data from an entire 1920 x 1080 screen.

In the test, it'll take about **4-5 seconds just to get the pixel data from a 15 x 15 area** of the screen.

```
width := 15 ; 1920
height := 15 ; 1080
searchResolution := 1 ; 3
columns := width / searchResolution
rows := height / searchResolution
resultRows := {}
columnCounter := 0
rowCounter := 0
resultCounter := 0

start := getTimestamp()
loop, %columns%
{
    resultRows[columnCounter] := {}
    loop, %rows%
    {
        PixelGetColor, pixelColor, columnCounter, rowCounter
        resultRows[columnCounter][rowCounter] := pixelColor
        rowCounter += searchResolution
        resultCounter += 1
    }
    columnCounter += searchResolution
    rowCounter := 0
}
end := getTimestamp()

MsgBox % "Finished! It took " . (end - start) / 1000 . 
" seconds to record pixel data from a " . 
width . " x " . height . " area of the screen (" . resultCounter . " pixels)."

getTimestamp()
{
    DllCall("QueryPerformanceCounter", "Int64*", timestamp)
    DllCall("QueryPerformanceFrequency", "Int64*", frequency)
    return Round(timestamp * 1000 / frequency)
}
```

If you'd like the version which includes debug logging and exporting of the data to an XML file for inspection, it's [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=51143831552275540843).

Is there any faster way to get pixel data from a portion of the screen?

`PixelSearch` searches very large areas of the screen very quickly, I'm not sure why `PixelGetColor` would be so very slow in comparison. There must be some `.dll` or some other function I can use to get pixel data from a small area of the screen much faster than this.

Comment: Perhaps take a screen shot and then iterate over the image to build the 2x2 array of pixel colors. Not sure if AHK will be able to achieve something like this. I just always used PixelGetColor.

Comment: Can anyone verify [if this code example works for them?](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/91585-screen-capture-using-only-ahk-no-3rd-party-software-required/) I was going to try to use it as a solution but the example code isn't saving a screenshot.

Comment: Learned that I needed to use the ansi 32 bit version of ahk for it to work. Still working out an overall solution to this..

Comment: @ChickenFeet It can if you use the right DLLs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do it 103 times faster than Forivin's solution :D

```
SetBatchLines, -1
CoordMode, Pixel, screen

FileDelete, Log.txt

searchSpace := 400
jumpSize := 1 ; how many units to skip each interval
total := Round(((searchSpace * searchSpace) / jumpSize), 0)
startTimer := getTimestamp()
getPixelMapSlow(searchSpace, jumpSize)
endTimer := getTimestamp()
duration := endTimer - startTimer
rate := total / duration
FileAppend, % "[getPixelMapSlow] Retrieved " . total . " pixels from bitmap, duration: " . duration . "ms at at a rate of " . rate . " pixels/ms.`n", Log.txt

searchSpace := 400
jumpSize := 1 ; how many units to skip each interval
total := Round(((searchSpace * searchSpace) / jumpSize), 0)
startTimer := getTimestamp()
getPixelMapFast(searchSpace, jumpSize)
endTimer := getTimestamp()
duration := endTimer - startTimer
rate := total / duration
FileAppend, % "[getPixelMapFast] Retrieved " . total . " pixels from bitmap, duration: " . duration . "ms at at a rate of " . rate . " pixels/ms.`n", Log.txt


getPixelMapFast(searchSpace, jumpSize){
    width := 1920
    height := 1080
    centerX := width / 2
    centerY := height / 2
    searchSpacehalf := searchSpace / 2
    searchCounterX := 0
    searchCounterY := 0
    pixelMap := {}
    pBitmap := Gdip_BitmapFromScreen((centerX - searchSpacehalf) . "|" . (centerY - searchSpacehalf) . "|" . searchSpace . "|" . searchSpace)
    E1 := Gdip_LockBits(pBitmap, 0, 0, Gdip_GetImageWidth(pBitmap), Gdip_GetImageHeight(pBitmap), Stride, Scan0, BitmapData)
    Loop, %searchSpace%
    {
        tick := A_Index * jumpSize
        if (tick < searchSpace) {
            New_Index_X := tick
            Loop, %searchSpace%
            {
                tick := A_Index * jumpSize
                if (tick < searchSpace) {
                    New_Index_Y := tick
                    color1ARGB := Gdip_GetLockBitPixel(Scan0, New_Index_X, New_Index_Y, Stride)
                    SetFormat, Integer, H
                    color1RGB := 0x00ffffff & color1ARGB
                    SetFormat, Integer, D
                    if (!pixelMap[New_Index_X]){
                        pixelMap[New_Index_X] := {}
                    }
                    pixelMap[New_Index_X][New_Index_Y] := color1RGB
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Gdip_UnlockBits(pBitmap, BitmapData)
    Gdip_DisposeImage(pBitmap)
    return pixelMap
}

getPixelMapSlow(searchSpace, jumpSize){
    width := 1920
    height := 1080
    centerX := width / 2
    centerY := height / 2
    searchSpacehalf := searchSpace / 2
    searchCounterX := 0
    searchCounterY := 0
    pixelMap := {}
    pBitmap := Gdip_BitmapFromScreen((centerX - searchSpacehalf) . "|" . (centerY - searchSpacehalf) . "|" . searchSpace . "|" . searchSpace)
    Loop, %searchSpace%
    {
        tick := A_Index * jumpSize
        if (tick < searchSpace) {
            New_Index_X := tick
            Loop, %searchSpace%
            {
                tick := A_Index * jumpSize
                if (tick < searchSpace) {
                    New_Index_Y := tick
                    color1ARGB := Gdip_GetPixel(pBitmap, New_Index_X, New_Index_Y)
                    if (!pixelMap[New_Index_X]){
                        pixelMap[New_Index_X] := {}
                    }
                    color1RGB := ARGBtoRGB(color1ARGB)
                    pixelMap[New_Index_X][New_Index_Y] := color1RGB
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Gdip_DisposeImage(pBitmap)
    return pixelMap
}

ARGBtoRGB( ARGB ) {
    VarSetCapacity( RGB,6,0 )
    DllCall( "msvcrt.dll\sprintf", Str,RGB, Str,"%06X", UInt,ARGB<<8 )
    Return "0x" RGB
}

getTimestamp()
{
    DllCall("QueryPerformanceCounter", "Int64*", timestamp)
    DllCall("QueryPerformanceFrequency", "Int64*", frequency)
    return Round(timestamp * 1000 / frequency)
}
```

Of course include the relevant functions of the AHK Gdip library (found on Github) in your code for this to work.

Log:

```
[getPixelMapSlow] Retrieved 160000 pixels from bitmap, duration: 33161ms at at a rate of 4.824945 pixels/ms.
[getPixelMapFast] Retrieved 160000 pixels from bitmap, duration: 321ms at at a rate of 498.442368 pixels/ms.
```

Comment: Another thing to consider might be not to calculate the RGB values, but keep the ARGB values and just work with those. The A component will always be `0x00` anyways.

Comment: @Forivin thanks, yeah when you're performing a calculation on 160000 loop iterations, that one string conversion being left out each time could make a big difference.

Comment: @Forivin actually your suggestion makes it 160 times faster rather than 100, wow.

Comment: Instead of defining the variable tick you could just use New_Index_X directly. And = is faster than := in many cases. I'm not sure if it would really help in your case, though.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you have a small error, your ARGB conversion is inverse, red is blue and blue is red. I've not dived into it, just noticed it's inverse compared to what the native getpixel returns

Answer (score 0):

To reduce delays between commands to a minimum you should also use `SetBatchLines, -1`. This alone can give you a significant performance boost.
I think you have already figured out the rest.
But in case anyone else stumbles across this question. Here is how you can do it with GDI+:

```
SetBatchLines, -1

#Include Gdip.ahk

pToken := Gdip_Startup()

; Screen area ("X|Y|Width|Height")
pBitmap := Gdip_BitmapFromScreen("500|600|300|100")

; Read RGB color from pixel x290 y65
ARGB := Gdip_GetPixel( pBitmap, 290, 65 )
pixelColor := ARGBtoRGB( ARGB )
MsgBox, % pixelColor

; Read RGB color from pixel x167 y90
ARGB := Gdip_GetPixel( pBitmap, 167, 90 )
pixelColor := ARGBtoRGB( ARGB )
MsgBox, % pixelColor


Gdip_DisposeImage(pBitmap)
Gdip_Shutdown(pToken)

ARGBtoRGB( ARGB ) {
    VarSetCapacity( RGB,6,0 )
    DllCall( "msvcrt.dll\sprintf", Str,RGB, Str,"%06X", UInt,ARGB<<8 )
    Return "0x" RGB
}
```

The code is mostly what I already posted [in another answer right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44627961/2879085).

Comment: See my answer. I found a way to do it 103x faster xD (run my code for benchmark)