# How can I get bitmap data from gdip libraries in AHK in a grid format?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm doing some kind of image recognition / motion detection and need to be able to access the pixel data from the screen with some manner of coordinates so I can see what color the pixel at [350,425] is and so on.

I recently asked [a question about getting pixel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621796/how-can-i-get-the-pixel-data-from-an-area-of-the-screen-much-faster-in-ahk?noredirect=1#comment76229522_44621796) from an area of the screen. The default method of viewing pixels in AHK is extremely slow (would take half a day to record the data from a 1080p screen). The answer seems to be using gdip libraries in AHK such as this one:

https://github.com/cswoyer/AutoHotkey/blob/master/ScreenCapture.ahk

However I have no idea how to get the pixel data during the process in a format that I can work with. I need to access the data in some sort of structure is accessible via x,y coordinates, or a format that follows some basic pattern so I can reformat it into a grid data structure and work with it.

I keep trying to check the various variables for any kind of text data that I can try to work with but none of them that I've tried seem to contain text or object data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but saving a screenshot in a variable and getting the pixels from there should be faster indeed. But obviously taking that screenshot will take a few milliseconds, so I'm not sure how useful this is gonna be in terms of "motion detection".

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetBatchLines, -1
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

#Include Gdip.ahk

pToken := Gdip_Startup()
pBitmap := Gdip_BitmapFromScreen() ; Make a screenshot

; Read RGB color from pixel x350 y425
ARGB := Gdip_GetPixel( pBitmap, 350, 425 )
pixelColor := ARGBtoRGB( ARGB )
MsgBox, % pixelColor

; Read RGB color from pixel x345 y567
ARGB := Gdip_GetPixel( pBitmap, 345, 567 )
pixelColor := ARGBtoRGB( ARGB )
MsgBox, % pixelColor


Gdip_DisposeImage(pBitmap)
Gdip_Shutdown(pToken)

ARGBtoRGB( ARGB ) {
 VarSetCapacity( RGB,6,0 )
 DllCall( "msvcrt.dll\sprintf", Str,RGB, Str,"%06X", UInt,ARGB<<8 )
 Return "0x" RGB
}
```

Credits to these two posts:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47007-get-pixel-color-from-a-bmp/?p=293766
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/91427-gdi-how-to-get-bitmap-from-certain-area-of-screen/?p=576860

Gdip.ahk can be found here: https://github.com/tariqporter/Gdip/blob/master/Gdip.ahk

Comment: Taking the screenshot is much faster if you're only capturing a 200 x 200 area of the screen, which I already figured out how to do with that library. I just needed to know how to access the pixels. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that would obviously make it much faster. Good to hear that it solved your problem.

Comment: For those who are interested, to only capture a certain area of the screen, you can pass a string of following format to `Gdip_BitmapFromScreen`: `X|Y|Width|Height`. E.g.: `Gdip_BitmapFromScreen("350|425|800|600")`.